# Can you use okta-auth-js with other OAuth2.0 Auth Code Flow providers?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, jwt, single-page-application, okta

I am building an sdk which allows the user to create a specialized single page application. I am using okta-auth-js and @okta/okta-react.

Will this code work with other Oauth2.0 providers?

eg:

```
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
  issuer: 'http://notokta.com/oauth2/default',
  clientId: '12345',
  redirectUri: 'derp', 
  theOtherConfigs: 'derp',
});

// The remaining okta-react boilerplate
```

Comment: We have not tested it with other providers. It might work, but no promises.

Comment: If you want a library which wasn't built with a concrete vendor in mind you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@curity/oauth-assistant or https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-client (which for now has no support but hopefully someone will pick it up)